# Why I have no 'User' object?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

New to React and Express, I have a problem in my login function. My register form work fine and I can post new user in my mongo DB.

When I use login form, the request go in my router, in my controller and in my model : I can console.log the data (email and password).

But when the data go into the function User.findOne, there is no user callback.

Any help will be appreciate ;)

```js
UserSchema.statics.authenticate = (email, password, callback) => {

    User.findOne({ email: email })
        .exec( (error, user) => {
            if (error) {
                return callback(error);
            } else if ( !user ) {
                console.log(user);
                let err = new Error('User not found.');
                err.status = 401;
                return callback(err);
            }
            const hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
            let hash_password = hash.update(password).digest('hex');

            if (hash_password === password){
                console.log(user);
                return callback(null, user);
            }
            else {
                return callback();
            }
        });
};
```

User is undefined and I always go into my 'else if'...

Comment: You should not be using unsalted sha1 (or sha1 at all)as a hashing mechanism for passwords. Use bcrypt. Here is a good reference: https://www.abeautifulsite.net/hashing-passwords-with-nodejs-and-bcrypt

Comment: Thx for your answer, but sha1 is a mantary of this project :D And my problem is before the sha1 encrypt ;)